# $\bar x$ value for $f(\bar x) = 4.5$ with tabled values

Tags: interpolation

The exercise asks for the $\bar x$ value as $f(\bar x) = 4.5$ using linear interpolation.

I couldn't reproduce a table with MathJax, so I'll put the tabled with data as:

$f(2) = 10$

$f(4) = 13$

$f(5) = 6$

$f(7) = 5$

$f(9) = 2$

Since I have $f(\bar x) = 4.5$ then my $\bar x$ value must be around $f(7) = 5$ and $f(9) = 2$.

Using linear interpolation, I found $P_{1}(x) = -1.5x - 5.5$
Now, replacing $P_{1}(x)$ for 4.5, I'll get $4.5 = -1.5x -5.5$ then $x = 6.666667$

But the answer is $7.333333$

I was expecting having to sum the $x$ value with an error number, but I couldn't find a way to calculate the error as well. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\bar{x}= \frac{(4.5-5)}{(2-5)}(9-7) + 7 = \frac{-0.5}{-3}\cdot2+7=7.333333$

Comment: Would you care to explain?

Comment: This is the natural result of linear interpolation between f(7) and f(9). BTW, the equation P1(x) = -1.5x - 5.5 cannot be right as it does not satisfy f(7)=5 or f(9)=2.